# Storing and accessing strings with a corresponding key value in Android application

Tags: java, android

I want to statically store some data that will be accessed based upon user choice.
E.g., I will have multiple (about 200 rows) of data in the format Name, Type, Shortname. In the user-interface, I want to present only Name and Type, and then upon click on one of them I want to return the third value (the shortname).

What data structure, or type, is the best for me to use for highest performance when using the data like I am?

Edit: I already know how to implement the ListView, and im only looking for some guidance (not a full implementation) on how to store the data for fast access from an user-interface, without doing something too complex..

Comment: Is data from a database or always the same (eg: from XML)?

Comment: If your data are not unique , you may want to add a sequence number and add them in `HashMap` with sequence number as key and data as value. If those records are unique, you can put them directly in `HashSet` ( which internally uses `HashMap` anyway ). Fetching data is very fast in `HashMap` if you know the `key` (is constant time of 1 ,assuming there are no hash collision ).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use realm to store data, it is not really complicated to use. Take a look at this https://auth0.com/blog/integrating-realm-database-in-an-android-application/. The thing is you can initialise your database with values in first application run eg.

```
private void realmConfiguration() {
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .initialData(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i){
                        Data data = realm.createObject(Data.class,i);
                        data.setData("Test "+i);
                    }
                }
            })
            //TODO: only for development
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
 }
```

Other thing is, that you should use RecyclerView than ListView. In this link above, it is shown too how to use RecyclerView.